Installing NVidia-driver 555 with ubuntu-drivers on Ubuntu 22.04
To be able to use CUDA 12.5, I had to update the drivers on my Ubuntu 22.04 to NVidia:555. For that, I wanted to use ubuntu-drivers, as described by https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation.
Consequently, running sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:555 should install all necessary drivers for that (respective upgrade the existing drivers from nvidia:545). However, after a reboot each time when calling nvidia-smi I get the error
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

There is also no entry in /proc/drivers corresponding to NVidia, and dkms status returns an empty line.
What exactly went wrong here, and how can I fix it, such that I can use CUDA 12.5 again?

You need to purge the driver you are replacing and then install the new one. That is how it works for Nvidia drivers. You will find on this site many questions where this is the answer..

I.e. this is not done automatically by ubuntu-drivers?

Already answered that, no it does not update you need to do as I described.

As I found out, ubuntu-drivers does apparently not install the driver itself, just additional packages. To solve my problem, I therefore had to install nvidia-driver-555 and nvidia-dkms-555 manually after executing sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:555. Now, nvidia-smi and all cuda-related functions work again as expected.
